# ionic3 SQLite unit testing

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I'm using ionic3 and am trying to unit test (using Jasmine/karma) the following code.  Can anyone offer any guidance.

```
createTable(databaseName: string): Promise<any> {

let sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table)';

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: databaseName + '.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(sql, [])
      .then(() => {
        console.info('Executed SQL');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error('createTable Error', e.message);
        reject(e);
      });
  });
})
}
```

Here's my work in progress attempt to test

```
describe('createTable()', () => {

let db: SQLiteObject;

it('Should call function createTable', () => {
  spyOn(service.sqlite, 'create').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(

  ));

  let databaseName = 'testDatabase';
  service.createEncounterTable(databaseName);
  expect(service.sqlite.create).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
});
```

I'm getting the following error return ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined', and dont seem to be able to gain access to executeSql.

As far as I can tell, from the lack of online resource on testing SQLite I have to assume that most people don't test this.  Thanks in advance to any guidance.